# QgsVectorLayer creation in Qthread (PyQt)

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, multithreading, qthread

Our QGIS project is dynamically generated on startup based on user roles. There are nearly 120 QgsVectorLayers that need to be generated. If created sequentially, the login process takes up to 2 minutes which is really annoying.

So, I thought I'll use a QThreadPool and create the layers in there. So, the threads basically just call this kind of code:

```py
class LayerLoaderWorker(QRunnable):
    
    def run(self):
        db_connect = DatabaseConnection()
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection(db_connect.host, str(db_connect.port), db_connect.dbname, db_connect.user,
                          db_connect.password)
        uri.setDataSource('public', self.viewname, 'geometry', '', 'id')
        
        locker = QMutexLocker(mutex)
        self.layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), self.layerSettings.displayname, "postgres")
        self.finished = True
        self.loader.workerFinished()
        locker.unlock()
```

Only the layers are created in the threads, after creation they are added to the `QgsProject` in the main (UI) thread.
Sometimes it seems to work, but most of the time the layers are not loaded correctly and the geometry column is empty.

Is the creation of the `QgsVectorLayer` object thread safe? It seems to me that this isn't the case. I read somewhere that UI-related things should be handled in the UI-Thread, but I thought creating the object (which seems to connect to the database which takes some time) is a non-ui-task.

Is it possible to load layers in parallel somehow?

Comment: Look at QgsTask. It is the usual method for background operations. The task shouldn't touch the GUI, as you have guessed.

Comment: I switched the layer loading to QgsTask, but unfortunately it still doesn't work correctly. I added the layer to the QgsProject in the finished()-Method of the task, since this method should be called from the main thread, as described here:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html

All layers are added to the mapTree, but most of them do not contain any features. I guess the creation of the QgsVectorLayer triggers stuff on the main thread or the dataprovider (postgres) is not thread safe. 

I guess I will give up, there seems to be no solution :-(

Comment: Always works for me, but I'm not using a database connection. There could be a timeout. I also use QgsTask.fromFunction() instead of subclassing.  I declare the task global, as it had problems when I didn't. Creating the vector layer in the thread is ok.

Comment: I found one interesting thing: When I try to update / reload the layer from QGIS itself, it tells me that there are already too many clients connected. Maybe I need to tell the QgsVectorLayer (or QGIS itself) to disconnect after creation?

Comment: I guess you should probably do that anyway, especially in your loop.

Comment: The problem is that the QgsVectorLayer is not deleted. I need to save the reference to do some things later in the finished() method. But as soon as I save the layer in a class member (self.layer), I am unable to close the connection.

```
        self.layer.deleteLater()
        del self.layer
        self.layer = None
```
I even tried to delete it manually, but the connection is not closed anymore.
If I create the layer without saving it in a member variable, the connections are closed again. I guess deleting the object in Python does not trigger the C++ destructor?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783238/python-database-connection-close - I know little about databases :-(

Comment: unfortunately this is all QGIS internal code, I don't create a db connection myself... I tried to delete the dataProvider manually, still no success. dp: QgsDataProvider = self.layer.dataProvider()

Comment: I will try to find a solution by reading the C++ sources, if this doesn't help I don't know what to do. Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: You may want to "trust" datasource at project level to speedup connection with `QgsProject.instance().setTrustLayerMetadata(True)` https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#a4fa7c9f272e7d7024bff273866e30a94 Mainly use for QGIS Server user but considering your number of layers, it could be also useful.

Comment: Not sure, you need to use threads. You may use service (from pg_service.conf file) to declare your layers. It will avoid opening multiple connection but reuse the service `uri.setConnection('servicename', None, None, None)` so no database check for each connexion or multiple connexions consumed due to each layer

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll give up, I tried everything I can think of. I deleted the object, I send the `deleteLater` signal to the metaObject of the task and so on. Nothing seems to work.

I used QThreads, QgsTasks as custom classes and now I tried to use `QgsTask.fromFunction`, nothing is working. As soon as the layer is returned, the db connection is never closed.

This is the example code I'm using right now:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class LookupLoaderData:
    businessTypeId: int
    layer: QgsVectorLayer
    public_table: str


def loadLookupTableLayer(task, businessTypeId):
    display_name = BusinessModel().getObjectDisplayName(businessTypeId=businessTypeId)

    QgsMessageLog.logMessage('loading lookup layer name "{}"'.format(display_name),
                             MESSAGE_CATEGORY, Qgis.Info)

    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setConnection(db_connect.host, str(db_connect.port), db_connect.dbname,
                      db_connect.user, db_connect.password)
    uri.setDataSource(schema, public_table, None, None, None)
    uri.setWkbType(QgsWkbTypes.NoGeometry)
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, "postgres")
    return LookupLoaderData(businessTypeId, layer, public_table)


def loadLookupTableLayerCompleted(exception, result: Optional[LookupLoaderData] = None):
    if not result or not result.layer:
        return
    oldName = result.layer.name()
    result.layer.setName(f'DEBUG ({result.businessTypeId}) {oldName}')
    result.layer.setReadOnly(True)
    layerTree = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup()
    layer_group = layerTree.findGroup("Lookups")
    if not layer_group:
        layer_group = layerTree.insertGroup(0, "Lookups")
    layer_group.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
    layer_group.setExpanded(False)
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result.layer, False)
    inserted_layer = layer_group.insertLayer(0, result.layer)
    inserted_layer.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
    inserted_layer.setExpanded(False)
```

The connections stay open and the database will eventually refuse further connections.
If I return something like this from the worker function:

```
return LookupLoaderData(businessTypeId, None, public_table)
```

The connections are closed because the object is killed, at least this is what I'm thinking :-)
According to the time it takes to load all these layers, the tasks are actually doing something, but unfortunately I'm unable to tell because now I have no layer object that can be added to the project and the `layerTree`.

It seems to be impossible to load vector layers in the background, at least with a postgres data provider.

Comment: You did db_connect.close() somewhere? Last ditch guess!

Comment: db_connect is just a dataclass with connection infos, only str and int values in there :-) I don't actively open the connection, this is all done by the dataProvider in the QgsVectorLayer

Comment: What DatabaseConnection library you using? pyodbc?

Comment: I only use a database library for reading some settings in our database, this is done by psycopg2 and sometimes QtSql for models that display and edit data in table views.

But the QgsVectorLayer connects by its own driver, I don't do anything here, I'm only specifying the connection type which is "postgres", the rest if done by QGIS.

Comment: Try deleting the QgsDataSourceUri or setting it to None instead of the databse parameters. Or listening to some other unqualified commentator :-)